# APDU command read SLE4432/42 card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I need migrate a application that read a SLE4432/42 card.

Now I use a [ACR reader](https://hashtips.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/pma-acr38xccid-6-02.pdf), with this APDU commands

```
FF A4 00 00 01 06 <- 4.1.1 SELECT_CARD_TYPE
FF B0 00 20 BE    <- 4.6.2 READ_MEMORY_CARD
```

But, now I need use a HID reader, but this don't work.

In [HID documentation](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-03099_a.2_-_omnikey_sw_dev_guide.pdf) said that READ_MEMORY_CARD is standard, but I don't find a standard SELECT_CARD_TYPE

Exist any standard APDU command for HID reader?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [this manual](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-03099_a.2_-_omnikey_sw_dev_guide.pdf), where chapter 8 covers synchronous cards as the SLE44 family.

Encoding seems to use class byte 0xFF too, but I have no idea, what you `FF A4` (with the instruction code of SELECT) is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks I read your manual. My second APU is standard, but first APU is reader specific. Exist a standar "SELECT_CARD_TYPE"?